# AC power control with using nuvoton M031 MCU

Tags: microcontroller, timer

I want to use Nuvoton M031 microcontroller with AC power control application. M031 is an Arm Cortex-M0 based microcontroller. I want to start Timer with using external interrupt. I did it. I configured GPIO port as input and I also configured it as interrupt.

I can start Timer in GPIO interrupt function. I am currently reading [technical reference manual](https://www.nuvoton.com/export/resource-files/TRM_M031_M032_Series_EN_Rev2.02.pdf) of M031 Series.

What I want to do is fire an interrupt when timer counter register is equal with timer compare register. I also want to fire another interrupt when timer overflows happens. I will stop timer in overflow interrupt. There are four different counting modes in Nuvoton M031. Timers of M031 do not fire an interrupt when timer overflow occurs. I don't want counter value to be 0 after firing interrupt. Only continous counting mode does that but it doesn't fire interrupt after overflow.

How can I do that with using M031? I used to work with Atmega328P. It has Timer/Counter Compare Match an also Timer/Counter Overflow interrupts. I am looking for similar thing.

Comment: `I don't want counter value to be 0 after firing interrupt` ... isn't the counter zero after an overflow?

Comment: @jsotola I dont wan't counter to go 0 after compare match interrupt happens. But yes it goes 0.

Comment: why is it a problem when the counter goes to zero?

Comment: @jsotola Because I need overflow after compare match interrupt.

Comment: overflow happens when a counter increments from 1111111111111 to 0000000000000, for example

Comment: @jsotola It happens only in timer continous couting mode but it does not mention anything about overflow interrupt. It only talks about timer compare match interrupt.